# How to get control on security privacy pop up in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, flash-cs5, webcam

We are working on flash camera project. We want to ask user to allow or deny camera access first on page load. then after few seconds we want to start camera and take photo. If User deny camera (or flash) access, we do not want to start camera. and If user allows permission for camera (or flash) access, we want to start camera and take photo.

For this, We are using "Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);". This code is user for ask permission to user about their camera access.

So, it is show Privacy Pop up in flash. But, how we can have control on that pop up. I mean, how we can know that is user checked on allow or deny check Box when user close pop up?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `Camera.getCamera().muted` - if it's false the user has allowed access to the camera, if not, he's not allowing access to it.

You can also listen to the `status` event on the camera object. When it changes from muted to unmuted, you'll get an event and can start the camera.

Comment: Thanks Laurent.......
working perfectly...
Thanks again for your wonderful help..

Comment: I have one more question if you can help me. can we have any control over security privacy pop up. I mean that I want to call function when user click on done button of privacy pop up.

Comment: You can't have direct control over this dialog box. However you can check some settings using event listeners and polling certain properties (like in this example where you check Camera.muted).