# Can we have any control over security privacy pop up in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, flash-cs5, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get control on security privacy pop up in flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424667/how-to-get-control-on-security-privacy-pop-up-in-flash)

Can we have any control over security privacy pop up in flash. I mean that I want to call function when user click on done button of privacy pop up.

We are using "Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);". This code is user for ask permission to user about their camera access.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful. Have a look:

[Detecting permissions for camera access](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSfffb011ac560372f3fa68e8912e3ab6b8cb-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d37)

I have just tried it and works perfectly. This code can be used in place of you permission dialog.

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
if (cam != null){ 
    cam.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler); 
    var vid:Video = new Video(); 
    vid.attachCamera(cam);
} 
function statusHandler(event:StatusEvent):void{ 
    if(event.code == Camera.Unmuted) // "Camera.Muted" or "Camera.Unmuted" 
        // good to go
    else
        // permission denied
}
```

This has an added advantage. If the user later on changes the camera permission from the setting box, then also the StatusEvent handler is fired

**Update**
I have tried and this also seems to work.

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
if (cam != null){ 
    cam.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler);
} 
function statusHandler(event:StatusEvent):void{ 
    if(event.code == "Camera.Unmuted") // "Camera.Muted" or "Camera.Unmuted" 
        trace("OK");// good to go
    else
        trace("NOK");// permission denied
}
Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
```

But the StatusEvent Handler is fired as soon as the radio button in the popup is clicked not after the Done button is clicked.